# Javascript await/async - Will this cause a race condition?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

Say I have a nodeJS server that uses Socket.IO. The one listener asynchronous, like so:

```
let aHugeArray = new Array(50000000);
// ... fill the array with data...

// print the array asynchronously:
socket.on('print-array', async () => {
    let isFinished = await printArray();
});

// remove an item from the array:
socket.on('remove-from-array', (item : any) => {
    let index = aHugeArray.indexOf(item);
    aHugeArray.splice(index, 1);
});

private async printArray() : Promise<boolean> {
    for (let i = 0; i < aHugeArray.length; i++) {
        console.log(aHugeArray[i]);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Assume I call `print-array` and then immediately call `remove-from-array` (which will execute before `print-array` finishes looping through the array. What will happen in this situation? Will the `remove-from-array` callback be blocked from manipulating `aHugeArray` before the loop is finished? Or will the array be manipulated, possibly causing strange results in the rest of the `print-array` loop iterations?

Comment: Your `printArray()` function is purely synchronous. Nothing else will happen until it finishes the iteration.

Comment: You might consider using a `Set` instead of an array - you won't have to search for the index, you can just `delete` an item from the set

Comment: @Pointy Really? So the entire application will be blocked until it finishes printing?

Comment: that's an interesting one. So even if the socket will receive a new message, for example `remove-from-array` one, the message will not be processed until the `printArray` is finished?

Comment: JavaScript does not have preemption.

Comment: @sme not necessarily — the `console.log()` interface may dispatch to some sort of separate worker context, like the Chrome console. However the `console.log()` API itself is synchronous with respect to the calling environment.

Comment: Understand that an `async` function is only *really* asynchronous if it internally actually does something asynchronously and returns a Promise. An ordinary synchronous function behaves identically if changed to have an `async` declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The print-array function isn't asynchronous, so unless you have one hell of a lot of memory, grabbing the contents of it and logging them wont noticably block the thread while waiting to run remove-from-array

If you have a function that you need to complete before something finishes, then promisify it

```
const IMightTakeSomeTime = new Promise ((resolve, fail) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(console.log('i am finished'))
    }, 3000);
})

IMightTakeSomeTime.then(() => 
    console.log('Now its my time to shine')
)
```

or you could use async / await if you want to get fancy

```
const IMightTakeSomeTime = new Promise ((resolve, fail) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(console.log('i am finished'))
    }, 3000);
})

const run = async () => {
    await IMightTakeSomeTime
    console.log('Now its my time to shine')
}

run()
```

If you want to see a well known non async thread blocking functions in action check out the synchronous version of the Node.js fs library where there are 'sync' versions of some of the functions that don't need to be awaited

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options

Comment: How can I make it print 'Now its my time to shine' first? (Before 'i am finished')? In other words, have the promise 'run in the background' while the rest of the app continues?

Comment: just take away the await ...
const IMightTakeSomeTime = new Promise ((resolve, fail) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(console.log('i am finished'))
    }, 3000);
})

const run = async () => {
    IMightTakeSomeTime
    console.log('Now its my time to shine')
}

run()